# fetching data-id in select tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm currently studying how to get the values inside html values using data-id but the result is undefined.

jquery inside function add_equipment()

```
var new_id = $( 'option:selected', this ).data( 'id' );
console.log( new_id );
```

i also tried:

```
var new_id = $(this).find(':selected').data('id'); 
console.log( new_id );
```

and

```
var new_id = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-id');
console.log( new_id );
```

my select tag

```
<select class="form-control product-name" id="product-name">
  <option value="default" selected disabled>Select Equipment Type</option>
  <option value="2.00" data-id="1">pencil </option>
  <option value="5.00" data-id="2">pen </option>
  <option value="7.00" data-id="3">marker </option>
</select>
```

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE.

Comment: And from where are you invoking `add_equipment` function? All above would have worked provided; you are using `this` in correct context

Comment: i have this button(<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="add_equipment();" data-dismiss="modal" >Add Equipment</button>) right below the select tag.

Comment: `<option value="default" selected disabled>Select Equipment Type</option>` don't have data-id .So it will always give `undefined` when loaded first time or going to be selected'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem with you implementation is that `this` refers to `window` object not `<select>` element, thus it didn't worked.

As you have provided `ID` attribute to `<select>` element, use it

```
var new_id = $('#product-name').find(':selected').data('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

you need use **data()** method to get **data-id** attribute id.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#product-name').on('change',function(){
    console.log($('#product-name option:selected').data('id'));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control product-name" id="product-name">
  <option value="default" selected disabled>Select Equipment Type</option>
  <option value="2.00" data-id="1">pencil </option>
  <option value="5.00" data-id="2">pen </option>
  <option value="7.00" data-id="3">marker </option>
</select>
```

try this one.